# Error while integrating RN FFMPEG in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, ffmpeg, podfile

```
**[!] There are multiple dependencies with different sources for `react-native-ffmpeg` in `Podfile`:
- react-native-ffmpeg (from `../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg/ios`)
- react-native-ffmpeg (from `../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg/ios/react-native-ffmpeg.podspec`)**
```

Getting this error.

```
- react-native-ffmpeg (from `../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg/ios/react-native-ffmpeg.podspec`)
```

I need this in podfile but the previous

- react-native-ffmpeg (from `../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg/ios`)
  is not even present in my podfile.

When I try to add a path it throws me the error. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the pod spec before the use_native_modules! line as mentioned in their documentation.
https://awesomeopensource.com/project/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'react-native-ffmpeg/audio', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native-ffmpeg/react-native-ffmpeg.podspec'

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
end
```